# How to read JSON and return value of an item?

Tags: c#, json

How to read and get the value of Framework Name (i.e. WinForms) from the below JSON File.

The method should be generic such a way that if user provides a particular path then for that it should get me the value.

For example : `GetValueFromJson("Framework/SolveTechnique/Available")` - The method should return true in this case

```
{
  "$type": "Config",
  "Available": true,
  "AdapterChecksums": {
    "$type": "UserList`2"
  },
  "Identification": true,
  "Verification": false,
  "Framework": [
    {
      "$type": "custom",
      "Name": "WinForms",
      "Technique": {
        "$type": "Technique",
        "PropertyName": "Name",
        "Available": true
      },
      "SolveTechnique": {
        "$type": "Userdefined",
        "Available": true
      },
      "AITechnique": {
        "$type": "AI",
        "X_Value": 2,
        "Y_Value": 3,
        "Available": true
      },
      "WaitTechnique": {
        "$type": "Recurssion",
        "Available": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Framework` is an array, what if there are multiple entries?

Comment: If you want custom paths provided by user you can take a look into json path which is supported by [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) for example.

Comment: @GuruStron -There won't be multiple entries. If there are multiple entries then consider the 1st one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guru Stron mentioned, you could use Newtonsoft Json to parse your json string. Calling "DeserializeObject" will give you a dynamic. Assuming you always want the first element of an array you could do something like:

```
    public object GetValueByQuery(string jsonString, string queryString)
    {
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
        var pathSegments = queryString.Split("/");
        return GetValue(obj, pathSegments);
    }

    private object GetValue(dynamic obj, string[] pathSegments)
    {
        if (obj is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)
        {
            return GetValue(obj[0], pathSegments);
        }

        var currPathSegment = ((JObject)obj).Children().FirstOrDefault(c => pathSegments[0].Contains(c.Path))?.Path ?? pathSegments[0];
        

        if (pathSegments.Length == 1)
        {
            return obj[currPathSegment];
        }

        return GetValue(obj[currPathSegment], pathSegments.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
```

Note there are multiple reasons this could fail.. there is no error handling.

Comment: Is there any way where I can have contains operator in the pathSegments. While getting the value for the path segments can it consider contains? Lets say in the above json file for some case it is "AdapterChecksums" and in some it is "AdapterChecksums-5A98". But to generalize I want to pass "AdapterChecksums" as the path segment

Comment: You try to find the name of the current path segment by doing something like: `var currPathSegment = ((JObject)obj).Children().FirstOrDefault(c => pathSegments[0].Contains(c.Path))?.Path ?? pathSegments[0];`

Comment: Getting null value.